# How to get the p-value for the full model from R's coxph?

Tags: r, cox-model

In a coxph model with 2 variables (let's say age and sex), how can I get the p-values for LR, Wald and score tests which I see in the summary(coxphobject) as below?

```
Concordance= 0.653  (se = 0.058 )
Rsquare= 0.085   (max possible= 0.924 )
Likelihood ratio test= 30.09  on 12 df,   p=0.002708
Wald test            = 34.73  on 12 df,   p=0.0005169
Score (logrank) test = 34  on 12 df,   p=0.0006736,   Robust = 17.61  p=0.1279
```

I think those values represented in the summary as `p=...` for each model are the p-values for the full model, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve them. If there is only one variate, let's say age, then I can retrieve the p-value using
`summary(coxphobject)$coefficients[5]`, which is the same as the one I see for the Wald test in the `summary(coxphobject)`. But when there are two variables (age and sex), `summary(coxphobject)$coefficients[1,5]` and `summary(coxphobject)$coefficients[2,5]` give the p-values for age and sex separately, but they both are different from the p-values I see for the full model in the `summary(coxphobject)` for LR, Wald and score tests.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Put `summary(coxphobject)` into a variable

```
summcph <- summary(coxphobject)
```

2) examine it with `str()`

```
str(summcph)
```

*Values! Values everywhere!*

so we find, (proceeding line by line in your above output):

a) the Concordance values

```
summcph$concordance
```

b) the Rsquare values

```
summcph$rsq
```

c) The Likelihood ratio test values

```
summcph$logtest
```

d) The Wald test values

```
summcph$waldtest
```

e) The score test values

```
summcph$sctest
```

f) The robust values

```
summcph$robscore
```

---

It *really* helps if you post a reproducible example, rather than make us go find your data set in order to check we're doing all the options the same. For example, you didn't mention you had a cluster term. (It would take an extra few moments for you, and would have saved me ten minutes while I tried to figure out why I couldn't get the last couple of values. At the least you could have mentioned which example you ran in the help!)